# Quebra de texto por delimitador

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte texto:

`Texto|Texto|Texto|`

Quero exibi-lo em um TextView, mas a cada "|" (pipe) ele quebrar a linha.

Desta forma:

```
String texto = this.textoQuebrado;
String[] array = texto.split("|");
conteudo.setText(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Sai assim:

`|T|e|x|t|o|||T|e|x|t|o|||T|e|x|t|o||`

Comment: `texto.replace("|", "\n");`

Comment: @Articuno não tem como sem usar quebra de linha ?

Comment: Na pergunta você diz `mas a cada "|" (pipe) ele quebrar a linha.`.

Comment: É verdade, eu que me perdi por conta de as vezes o \n não ser reconhecido, mas é outra coisa ! Viajei ! Valeu !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente com [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String texto = "Texto|Texto|Texto|";
System.out.println(texto.replace("|", "\n"));
```

Saida:

```
Texto
Texto
Texto
```

Veja: https://ideone.com/hp9Jj7

Lembrando que o componente `TextView` aceita quebras de linhas utilizando o `\n` normalmente.